# The truth value of a dataframe is ambiguous only when running it through Tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, treeview

I have a function that is supposed to calculate the Mean and Median of some values in a pandas dataframe and then display them via Tkinter Treeview. I've tested the function without Tkinter and it works perfectly, but if I run it with it, it gives this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

This my code:

```
def zip_mean_median():
    global clean_df
    clean_df['ACTIVITY DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(clean_df['ACTIVITY DATE']).dt.normalize()
    clean_df = clean_df.sort_values(by=['ACTIVITY DATE'])
    clean_df = clean_df.groupby([clean_df['ACTIVITY DATE'].dt.year, 'FACILITY ZIP'])['SCORE'].agg(['mean', 'median'])
    clean_df = ttk.Treeview(clean_df)
    clean_df.pack()
```

Comment: Please only ask one question. It's not clear what this question is mainly about.

Comment: `clean_df` is a `pd.DataFrame`. You cannot pass it as the master of a `Treeview`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a dataframe directly to `ttk.Treeview`, you need to manually construct it. That can be done with the following function

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def dataframe_to_treeview(root, dataframe):
    tree = ttk.Treeview(root, show='headings')
    columns = list(dataframe.columns)

    tree["columns"] = columns
    tree.pack(expand=tk.TRUE, fill=tk.BOTH)

    for i in columns:
        tree.column(i, anchor=tk.W)
        tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor=tk.W)

    for i, row in dataframe.iterrows():
        tree.insert("", "end", values=list(row))

    return tree
```

As an example, you can use this function as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

inp = [{'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '100', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'GBP', 'Volume': '200', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'CAD', 'Volume': '300', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '400', 'Country': 'SE'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '100', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'GBP', 'Volume': '200', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'CAD', 'Volume': '300', 'Country': 'DK'},
       {'Currency': 'EUR', 'Volume': '400', 'Country': 'DK'},
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
root = tk.Tk()
tree = dataframe_to_treeview(root, df)
root.mainloop()
```